# How to find MemoryMonitor tools in AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-memory

Where can I find `MemoryMonitor` tool in `AndroidStudio` 1.3.2 ?

I have already tried `Tools` --> `Android` but there is no MemoryMonitor .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down on IDE, open tab `Android` and there you can find `Memory` or `CPU`

[image: img]